# How to get the folder of the recent document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I run a script inside a google document. How can I get the recent folder where this document is in, or how do I create a subfolder of the recent folder of my document?

I want to create a subfolder but this subfolder always is created on the top level in google drive.

```
`if (!DriveApp.getFoldersByName("myNewFolder")) DriveApp.createFolder("myNewFolder");`
```

So it seems that the active folder is the toplevel folder.

There is no `DocumentApp.getMyFolder()` or `DriveApp.getRecentFolder()` method.
Is there maybe some kind of LINUX-style pre-thing like

```
DriveApp.createFolder("./myNewFolder");
```

So how do I get the recent folder, or - even better - How do I create a new folder in the recent folder and then create a new document inside this new folder? Remark: The folder should only be created new if it does not already exist.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Create a folder in a folder in Goolge Drive (directly, without moving) where a Google Document is stored.

**Solution**

1. This sample utility function gets the parent `Folder` of a file by its Id:

   ```
   /**
    * Gets file location;
    * @param {String} id document id;
    * @return {Folder|null} file's folder; 
    */
   function getLocation(id) {
     var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
     var folders = file.getParents();
     if(folders.hasNext()) {
       return folders.next();
     }else {
       return null;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Get the parent folder of the current document (assuming your script is bound to the document, otherwise procure the Id by other means):

   ```
   function createSubfolderInCurr() {
     var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
     var folder = getLocation(id);

     if(folder) {
       //part 3 goes here;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Check if a subfolder already exists and create one if needed:

   ```
   var exists = folder.getFoldersByName('myNewFolder').hasNext();
   if(!exists) {
     var newfolder = folder.createFolder('myNewFolder');

     //part 4 goes here;
   }
   ```
4. As for creating a new document in that folder, first you need to create a `Document`, then access it as a `File` and move from `root` to the newly created folder:

   ```
   var newdoc = DocumentApp.create('NewFile');
   var newId = newdoc.getId();
   var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);

   DriveApp.removeFile(newfile);
   newfolder.addFile(newfile);
   ```

**Reference**

1. `getParents()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents);
2. `getFoldersByName()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFoldersByName(String)) ('Folder' class);
3. `createFolder()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFolder(String)) (`Folder` class);
4. `create()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname) (`DocumentApp` class);
5. `removeFile()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removeFile(File)) (`DriveApp` class);
6. `addFile()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)) (`Folder` class);

Comment: Wow! Works like charm and so well described! Thank you very much!

Comment: @OliverRafelsberger - not at all! I've also added the conditional you asked about (although, your comment is no longer available, so I am not sure whether the file is to be created regardless of the subfolder existence - but that's easy to change)

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out on my own. For this I removed the commet. But your answer is now very complete. At step 3 I now have something like:
`    var newFolder;
    if (folder.getFoldersByName(docName).hasNext()) {          // check if a folder of that name already exists.
      newFolder = folder.getFoldersByName(docName).next();     // im yes then use it
    } else {
      newFolder = folder.createFolder(docName);                // else create a new folder
    }`

Comment: I've edited the original question so now your answer perfectly matches.

Comment: @OliverRafelsberger, no need to edit but thanks - glad I could help :) Yep, that's the way if you need to create file regardless of whether the folder is the existing or a new one